# Calling a function using exec

Tags: python, exec

Trying to call a function as a string using exec but it doesn't work.  I attached a simple example code below.

I get an error that square_it() is missing 1 required positional argument: 'num.'  I know it is missing but I don't know how to have the argument in that globals syntax.

Below is an example:

```
def square_it(num):

    result = num * num
    return result

def test():

    #code_globals = {}
    globals()['square_it']()
    code_locals = {'testing':0}
    comd_str = "testing = square_it(2)"
    exec(comd_str, globals(), code_locals)
    print(code_locals['testing'])


test()
```

Comment: If you read the traceback for the error closely, you'll see that it is ocurring on line the `globals()['square_it']()` because that is where the function is being called with no arguments — not via the `exec()` (execution never gets that far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't happening in the exec call; it's happening in the first line, when you call globals. All the rest of the code is irrelevant.

Calling the function there is *exactly* the same as doing it any other way; you have the calling parentheses, you just need to put your argument in there:

```
globals()['square_it'](2)
```